# Automatically compiling object files on save in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-construction

In Eclipse, is there a way for, when I save a code file, to compile the object file for the file saved, and then link them together when I go to run or debug? This is with C++ on Linux with GCC.

Comment: And what about when you save header file? Would you want to compile all cpp files that include that file? That could take some time..

Comment: IIRC, auto build is on by default.

Comment: Actually, I was unaware that it was a behavior built into Eclipse, but after poking around in the project settings I found the option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  In Eclipse CDT build process is started explicitly.  I think that "Build automatically" option is used for Java and other languages which Eclipse knows how to build.  C++ projects are usually built using some kind of make utility.  You can customize your make file to set different build targets to improve performance and reduce build/compile times.